# Equillibria to Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering what the exact definition is of an equilibrium to a differential equation. It seems like the general consensus implies that a differential equation will only have an equilibrium if it is autonomous. But, why would this be? If the equation was not autonomous, such as $\frac{dy}{dt}=t^2(t^2+1)$ why should $t=0$ not be an equilibrium solution? My feeling behind this is that the goal is to determine when $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$. But, why does one only care about $y(t)$ and not $t$ alone? $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ would be the case regardless of whether the equation is autonomous or not.

Comment: The solution you're looking for is a function $y(t)$, so the phrase "$t=0$ is a solution" is completely meaningless in this context.

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry if I made it seem that way, maybe I didn't ask my question appropriately. I meant that why shouldn't we say that $t=0$ is an equilibrium solution? When most texts ask one to find the equilibrium solution, they are only concerned with, like you said, functions $y(t)$, but why is this?

I don't understand that if it is the goal to determine when $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ why values of $t$ alone, are not considered adequate equilibrium solutions.

Comment: In problems like this the variable $t$ usually represents time, and you are given $y(0)$ and want to figure out $y(t)$ for all $t>0$, i.e., to predict the future of your system given the initial state. An equilibrium solution is a solution which remains the same for all time. (Equilibrium = no change.)